# Cloud console on raspberry pi

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, raspberry-pi, google-translate

I want to run the cloud console on my raspberry pi to access the apis on my account, however it says the chromium (raspberry pi browser) does not support the cloud console (most likely because it is outdated). Is there any way to access the cloud console from the raspberry pi? I know this has been done before because of the project attached to the message.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvZRm-cqE7s

if anyone can help that would be great

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.